# Window manager error: Failed to get proc address for 'eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT'

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-17.04

I used 'ubuntu 17.04' system in VirtualBox.And After i ticked the `3D acceleration` up.

There are some `gnome-shell`'s prettification became disable.

And the `Gnome Tweak Tool` lost the option of `shell theme`.

So I tryed to start the `gnome-shell`.But I get the error return that:

```
Window manager error: Failed to get proc address for 'eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT'
```

And When i canceled the `3D acceleration` down.

I can't enter the system's lock screen.

It show full black all over the screen and didn't return any message.

My VirtualBox is `5.1.28`.And host system is win10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
```